# nested query of @ManyToOne in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using jpa and hibernate. a have two classes:

```
@Entity(name = "constant")
@Table(name = "CONSTANT")
public class Constant extends BaseEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "CONSTANT_SEQ")
   private Long constantID;

   private String title;

}

@Entity(name = "constantValue")
@Table(name = "CONSTANT_VALUE")
public class ConstantValue extends BaseEntity {

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "CONSTANT_VALUE_SEQ", name = "CONSTANT_VALUE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "CONSTANT_VALUE_SEQ")

   private Long constantValueID;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "CONSTANT_ID")
   private Constant constant;
}
```

when I try to make the query, I get an exception. here's my query:

```
     select o from constantValue o where o.constant.constantID=4 and (upper(o.constant.title) like upper(:constant.title) )
```

how can I use o.constant.title in my query?

here's the exception:

```
23-Feb-2018 14:02:05.036 SEVERE [http-apr-8082-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
            java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:562)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4540)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1242)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4252)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.functionCall(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2429)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1320)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3877)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1923)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1873)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1873)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1851)
```

Comment: What is the Exception you get?

Comment: here's my exception: rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post some Application-Code?

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post, **in the question**, not in comments, the **complete** stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. This exception doesn't seem to have anything to do with the JPQL query. It's invalid, though, since your entity is named `ConstantValue` and not `constantValue`, and since `:constant.title` is invalid.